# Цикл while является устаревшим?

Tags: javascript, while

В [Уроках Javascript с нуля. Урок 6 - Циклы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZovBvi_YBcg) 
утверждается, что этот цикл устаревший (между 13 и 15 минутами). Так ли это?

Comment: Он это обосновывает? (Не смотрел)

Comment: Не учитесь по видеоурокам...

Comment: Кусочек из видео: *Эти цикли устаревшие, ними никто не пользуется..*. Покажите хоть одного, кто не использует `while`? Даже сам автор его использовал)))) Не люблю верить людям, которые вооружены только своими допущениями..

Answer (score 2):

Я не гуру JavaScript, но могу сказать точно, что while нужный цикл.

В том видео не приводятся доводы его устаревания.

Да, можно обойтись без while, используя какой-нибудь бесконечный for(;;) с каким-нибудь хитрым условием внутри, но с while- это выглядит естественнее и ты сразу же даешь понять свои мотивы.

Это все равно, как сказать, что в C# циклы не нужны, так как есть LINQ, но он не всегда уместен.

Answer (score 0):

Исторически, *JavaScript* имел сначала только цикл `while`; цикл `for` был добавлен позже. В эти время не было другого способа, как записать цикл, в котором на каждом шаге увеличивается какая-то переменная.

Автор очевидно имеет на мысли программистов, которые постоянно используют цикл `while` в ситуациях, когда цикл `for` больше удобным и больше понятным.